# Android Galaxy Nexus - Localhost HTTP request not working when 3G connection is on

Tags: android, http, 3g, samsung-mobile

I am having a problem making HTTP request to localhost on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Android version 4.0.2).

I am running a local http server on the Android phone for some research project. The idea is that an Android application communicates with this local server using HTTP methods (GET,PUT,etc).

The problem is the following:

- When I make an HTTP request to localhost or 127.0.0.1 with the Wi-Fi turned on everything works fine and I am able to reach the server.

  - However, when I try to do the same with the Wi-Fi turned off and using a 3G connectivity I get a in the response status line: **HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway**
  - Lastly, if I attempt to do an HTTP request to other IP (www.google.com) over 3G connectivity, the HTTP response code is 200 OK.

Another strange fact is that running the same code on a Sony Ericsson Xperia arcS does not create the problem and everything works fine.

My guess is that there is a problem with the Samsung Galaxy Nexus when I attempt to do an HTTP call to localhost using the 3G connection. However, I don't understand why with other IP addresses it works perfect.

Any suggestions or someone with a similar problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't think a 3g/4g connection is going to allow the phone to act as an HTTP server. Probably the carrier prevents this from happening. Just a guess though.

Comment: I would think something similar but the same code works in the Sony Ericsson Xperia with the same operator.

Comment: And even that the carrier would prevent it, http request to localhost should not go out to the network or am I wrong?

Comment: Is your Arc S upgraded to ICS or is it still on 2.3.x?

Comment: It is already upgraded to ICS

Comment: Same issue here, using a Nexus 4 with the latest stock OS (Kit-Kat 4.4.2). One thing I've noticed is that accessing http://localhost/  or http://127.0.0.1/ directly in the browser while on 3G will sometimes end up going to an internal router login/config page from my mobile provider. So it looks like localhost requests are somehow all going out over the 3G interface, not to loopback.

Answer (score 0):

Because localhost is only accessable using local network and you have to put your content on an online hosting and access it using an address or an IP address 
for example the localhost IP address on the local network is 192.168.1.2 and you are trying to access this address from android using 3g , the 3g connection doesn't have access to local network resources and addresses so it will throw ,`UnknownHostException` or some thing similar
hope this wold help